# how to save a graph with multiple functions to png using type="cairo"

Tags: r, png, plotrix

I successfully created a script which produces a nice plot in RStudio:

`abscissa = nrow(LoopVariable)
     library(plotrix) 
     plotCI(1:abscissa, LoopVariable[ ,13],
            uiw=LoopVariable[ ,"F_corrected_normed_error"], err="y",
            main=(LoopVariable[1,"Samples..Sample_ID"]),
            xlab="", ylab="correct Y axis",
            pch=19)
     abline(h=LoopVariable[1,"mean_fraction-modern"], lwd=2, col="red")
     mtext("no additional error added")`

So far so good.
Then I wrote this code:

`png(filename=paste0("I:/C14Data/QualityControl/Johannes/code_output/", 
        RNumberList[i], "_", date, " (R#_yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss).png"),
        type="cairo",
        units="cm",
        width=abscissa,
        height=10,
        pointsize=12,
        res=96)
        plotCI(1:abscissa, LoopVariable[ ,13],
               uiw=LoopVariable[ ,"F_corrected_normed_error"], err="y",
               main=(LoopVariable[1,"Samples..Sample_ID"]),
               xlab="", ylab="fraction modern",
               pch=19)
    dev.off()`

This exports a png file just as I want it, `BUT`: How can I add the following two lines to the export function and get it to look excactly the same as the previous code?:

    `abline(h=LoopVariable[1,"mean_fraction-modern"], lwd=2, col="red")
    mtext("no additional error added")`

Comment: What exactly is wrong when you just add those two lines? Do you not know where to add them? You should just put them in before the `dev.off()`.

Comment: Thanks `@MrFlick'. I tried this before and it did not work. Perhaps I need to restart RStudio more frequently.

Comment: What does "did not work" mean exactly? Did you get an error? Was a file not created at all? Was a file created but without the abline? It helps to be as specific as possible. It would also be helpful to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that we could also run to reproduce the error.